# How many hours between two time?(unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time')

Tags: python, datetime

I tried to calculate how many hours between 10:49 and 16:38 by the type of `float`.

```
import datetime
t1 = datetime.time(10,49,00)
t2 = datetime.time(16,38,00)
t = (t2 - t1).hours
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate like that :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

t1 = datetime.strptime("10:49:00", "%H:%M:%S")
t2 = datetime.strptime("16:38:00", "%H:%M:%S")
t = (t2 - t1)
print t.total_seconds() / 3600

print timedelta(days=0, seconds=t.seconds, microseconds=t.microseconds)
print ceil(t.total_seconds() / 3600)
```

Output:

```
5.81666666667
5:49:00
6.0
```

And get hour from timedelta :

```
x = timedelta(days=0, seconds=t.seconds, microseconds=t.microseconds)
print x.seconds//3600
```

Output is 5.

Comment: `t` is already a `timedelta`. You can just `t.total_seconds() / 3600`

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple typo. You're calling for `.hours` but actually the keyword is `.hour`

Try going with `t = t2.hour - t1.hour`

From Python interpreter:

```
>>> t1 = datetime.time(10,49,00)
>>> t2 = datetime.time(16,38,00)
>>> t = t2.hour - t1.hour
>>> t
6
```

But just so you know, if you want to use the `.hour` keyword, it's useless to use a float, because it will always return `x.0` because whatever full hours you decide to subtract, you will never get a float that isn't `.0`

Answer (score 2):

`datetime.time` does not support the subtraction operator. Since you already have the hours and minutes as integers, you might as well calculate the difference yourself.

```
print(((16 * 60 + 38) - (10 * 60 + 49)) / 60)
```

This outputs:

```
5.816666666666666
```

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't support subtraction? I guess because it's not clear which day each time lies on, so the answer could be off by 24hrs? I couldn't find a reference for why it's not supported.

Comment: Yes, I believe the lack of date information is the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a very similar solution to your proposal by using `datetime.datetime` and adding a dummy date (e.g. the first day of this year). Furthermore, you may only ask for `days` and `seconds`.

```
import datetime
t1 = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,10,49,00)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,16,38,00)

difference = (t2 - t1)
difference.days * 24 + difference.seconds // 3600

> 5
```